# Libgdx handle screen resolutions

Tags: libgdx, resolution, viewport

I know there are some questions to this topic, but i didnt find a 
satisfying answer for my problem yet.

I'm learning to use libgdx right now, and I'm not sure about handling different screen resolutions. I can use Viewports and a Camera of course, to fit the content
to the screen. But - how do i achieve, that my game doesnt appear kind of stretched if a device has a different resolution?

For example: Do you know the game Clash Royale? It feels like this game looks the same on all devices with every different resolution and screen size.
How do they do this?

Thank you.

Comment: you didnt link the stackoverflow question

Comment: There is already [a similar question on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198932/how-to-deal-with-different-aspect-ratios-in-libgdx) and it seems you are right: [to use a viewport and a camera](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) is the solution.

Comment: Corrected. I posted a new comment as I couldn't edit my previous one.